# jQuery .val() doeen't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, safari, woocommerce

I have an issue with a script that doesn't work in Safari.

This script should change the **continue** button on the woocommerce checkout page if a specific payment gateway is selected. This script doesn't work only in Safari.

Specifically at this line:

```
jQuery('input#place_order').val('Weiter zur Finanzierung')
```

All other parts of this script work. I tried to change `.val()` to `.attr()`, but it didn't solve the problem either.

```
<div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment">
 <ul class="wc_payment_methods payment_methods methods">
  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_bacs">
    <input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="">
    <label for="payment_method_bacs">Vorkasse</label>

    <div class="payment_box payment_method_bacs" style="display: none;">
        <p>Nach dem Zahlungseingang auf unser Konto, wird die Ware entsprechend der Verfügbarkeit schnellstmöglich versandt. Unsere Bankverbindung sehen Sie in der Zusammenfassung Ihrer Bestellung und zusätzlich in der darauf folgenden Bestätigungsmail.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_jetpack_custom_gateway">
    <input id="payment_method_jetpack_custom_gateway" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="jetpack_custom_gateway" data-order_button_text="">
    <label for="payment_method_jetpack_custom_gateway">Finanzierung ab 0 % </label>
    <div class="payment_box payment_method_jetpack_custom_gateway" style="display: block;">
            <p>Im nächsten Schritt sehen Sie die Zusammenfassung Ihrer Bestellung und den weiterführenden Link „Finanzierungsangebot berechnen und Antrag stellen“. Sie können Laufzeit und monatliche Rate auswählen. Mit einem effektiven Jahreszins von 0% (6 – 36 Monatsraten) oder 6,9% (48 – 72 Monatsraten).</p>
    </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="form-row place-order">
  <p class="form-row terms wc-terms-and-conditions">
   <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
   <label for="terms" class="checkbox">Ich  erkläre mich mit den <a href="https://www.hifi-systeme.de/agb-2/" target="_blank">AGB </a> einverstanden. <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <input type="hidden" name="terms-field" value="1">
  </p>

   <input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Zahlungspflichtig bestellen" data-value="Zahlungspflichtig bestellen">
   <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="1395845530"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/kasse/?wc-ajax=update_order_review">  
  </div>
</div>

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('body')
    .on('updated_checkout', function() {
      usingGateway();
      jQuery('input[name="payment_method"]').change(function() {
        usingGateway();
      });
    });
});

function usingGateway() {
  console.log(jQuery(".payment_method_jetpack_custom_gateway input[name='payment_method']:checked").val());

  if (jQuery('.payment_method_jetpack_custom_gateway input[name="payment_method"]:checked').val() == 'jetpack_custom_gateway') {
    jQuery('input#place_order').val('Weiter zur Finanzierung');
  } else {
    //console.log("Not using my gateway. Proceed as usual");
  }
}
```

Comment: any console errors in the safari console?

Comment: Try using jQuery('#place_order').val('Weiter zur Finanzierung');

Comment: Please add relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Hey, i have added the HTML-Markup. And no there aren't any errors in the safari console.

Comment: Can you try to replace `input type="submit"` to `button type="submit"`?

Comment: @31piy that the script will change `input type="submit"` to  `button type="submit"`? Or what do you mean :)?

Comment: @Bennet -- No! I meant to change your HTML. Don't use `input` tag. Use `button` instead.

Comment: That markup comes from Woocommerce and if i cange it, it doesen't work.

if i paste the line `jQuery('input#place_order').val('Weiter zur Finanzierung')` in the Safari-Console than the button gets changed.

Comment: @31piy if i put an timeput around `jQuery('input#place_order').val('Weiter zur Finanzierung')` then it works. But this is not a good solution: `setTimeout("jQuery('#place_order').val('Weiter zur Finanzierung');", 5000);`

Comment: Ok I think I'll leave it that way and set the timeout on 100ms. Thats works.